# Getting font size from Tesseract

Tags: font-size, tesseract

I know I can get font name using GetWordFontAttributes().FontName but I can't find how to get font size.
I thought GetWordFontAttributes().PointSize was it but I was wrong.
Does anyone know?

Comment: Would this be of any help? http://pastebin.com/0dV84hBa

Comment: The link talks about GetWordFontAttributes().PointSize.
But I tried that and the font size is very different from what it should be.